# Excel Table Value Change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel, Table1. The value in ColumnA is changed by formula rather than user input. When a value in ColumnA changes I would like to populate the corresponding row in ColumnB with the same value as ColumnA if ColumnB value is null. How can i achieve this using VBA, I believe I need to use the Worksheet Calculate event.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you need to use the Worksheet Calculate event to check the change in the result of a formula.

Comment: How can I determine which row has changed without using Target

Answer (score 0):

This will at-least move your values based on your criteria.  No event code, havent figured that out yet..

Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro
'

'Initialize variables

Dim r As Range

Dim r1 As Range

Dim b As Range

'set range as column A

Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ColumnA").DataBodyRange

'set range as column B

Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ColumnB").DataBodyRange

'**Loop through each cell in column "B" and assign to A value if 0

For Each b In r1.Cells

```
If b = 0 Then
b = Cells(b.Row, b.Column - 1)

End If


Next b
```

End Sub